# Save a file with username and password to sdcard and reading whether it exists in database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-file

guys i two edit text values which i need to save to text file into sdcard which will be basically username and password.

After storing it i need to read that file and check whether the username and password which is in text file is in database or not.

I am using php and mysql as database.

Code for saving the file to sdcard:

```
try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

how to acheive this please help

Comment: Why don't you use SQLlite database instead of storing it on SD card

Answer (score 0):

To read username and password from file you can try something like this and change it accordint to what you need:

```
 int rme = 0;    
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file path");
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 String str;

// read data accoridng your need in my case this is how i did it in java.

 while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
  rememberme= str.toString();
  rme=Integer.parseInt(rememberme);
  str = br.readLine();
  uname=str.toString();
  str = br.readLine();
  password=str.toString();        
 } 
//rme=Integer.parseInt(uname);
```

return rme;

Comment: thanks but will it read both username and  password seperately?

Comment: yes you can read them both in two strings separately. I saved int in first line, username in second and password in third line thats why needed  break line in between to separate.